# JSON Path String Evaluation of root value

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

Have a service that returns a very basic json respons:

```
{
    "methodresult": "error",
    "ErrorCode": 2,
    "ErrorCodeText": "format",
    "ErrorMessage": "Json parse exception at pos:171 msg:Expecting \"key\""
}
```

And am trying to use JSONPath to query if the "methodresult" value is coming back as "error".

Based on the documentation/examples I've seen I would expect this to work:

```
$[?(@.methodresult=="error")]
```

However based on validators I'm utilizing like this (https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) am not seeing any boolean response.

When trying to write an expression against something not in an array is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

Include the json response within square brackets and it works.

```
[{
"methodresult": "error",
"ErrorCode": 2,
"ErrorCodeText": "format",
"ErrorMessage": "Json parse exception at pos:171 msg:Expecting \"key\""
}]


$[?(@.methodresult=="error")].methodresult
```

Result:

```
[  
"error"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you are missing anything.

The problem is in the lack of a true *standard* for JSONPath. There are a few ideas/proposals (including a somewhat related one for [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901), which has been stuck in 'PROPOSED STANDARD' phase for years now), many implementations, and they are all different in some way even when they supposedly implement the same proposal (e.g. [Stefan Goessner's one](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)).

For example, when using [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), these JSONPath expressions

```
$.[?(@.methodresult == 'error')]
 $[?(@.methodresult == 'error')]
 .[?(@.methodresult == 'error')]
  [?(@.methodresult == 'error')]
```

produce the same result for the input JSON from the question:

```
{
    "methodresult": "error",
    "ErrorCode": 2,
    "ErrorCodeText": "format",
    "ErrorMessage": "Json parse exception at pos:171 msg:Expecting \"key\""
}
```

They return a non-empty array containing the JSON object that has `methodresult` field equal to `error`. And that is to be expected if one looks at Stefan Goessner's proposal...

Trying those same expressions for the given input [here](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) (link provided in the question) or [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) (which offers running a given JSONPath expression using 4 different implementations), and the results will be mixed: failed parsing, execution errors, an empty array, and sometimes as expected.

The bottom line is that, until there is a true *standard* for JSONPath, the only way to make sure a JSONPath expression works as expected is to write it for the *concrete* JSONPath implementation that you will be using in your application.